# Can't call EnumWindows function while member of a class

Tags: c++, windows, class, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to call "enumWind" with EnumWindows(). The EnumWindows is from the WinAPI...

```
WINUSERAPI BOOL WINAPI EnumWindows(_In_ WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, _In_ LPARAM lParam);
```

And it works fine, but I want to put it inside a class. Then it does not work anymore, saying that "argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type".

Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "BOOL (__stdcall DirectX_Hook::*)(HWND handle, LPARAM lp)" is incompatible with parameter of type "WNDENUMPROC"

mycode.h

```
class DirectX_Hook
{
public:
    BOOL CALLBACK enumWind(HWND handle, LPARAM lp);
    HWND GetProcessWindow();
    // Other functions that doesn't matter to you.
}DX_Hook;
```

mycode.cpp

```
BOOL CALLBACK DirectX_Hook::enumWind(HWND handle, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD ProcID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &ProcID);
    if (GetCurrentProcessId() != ProcID)
        return TRUE;

    window = handle;
    return FALSE;
}

HWND DirectX_Hook::GetProcessWindow()
{
    window = NULL;

    EnumWindows(enumWind, NULL); // <- The error, but not an error when i remove "DirectX_Hook::" from the function name
                                 // Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "BOOL (__stdcall DirectX_Hook::*)(HWND handle, LPARAM lp)" is incompatible with parameter of type "WNDENUMPROC"

    RECT size;
    GetWindowRect(window, &size);
    windowSize.x = size.right - size.left;;
    windowSize.y = size.bottom - size.top;

    return window;
}
```

Comment: *argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type* - but this is true. signature of this 2 functions mismatch. you need use *static* function and pass *this* pointer via *lParam*

Comment: @RbMm It is working now. But why does it have to be a static function?

Comment: but not static function have additional parameter - *this*. you forget about this.

Comment: @ThomasHansen because a `static` class method does not have the hidden `this` parameter, which is what is making a non-static class method incompatible.

Comment: Because non-static member functions do not have a compatible calling convention with free or static member functions. nNon-static members require the 'this' pointer (however the CC provides it). Regular functions would not provide this, and even if you massaged the function so that the compiler thought it was void (*)(ObjType *) 'this' may be passed in some special way that is different from regular parameters.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir the issue has nothing to do with calling conventions.  Static, non-static, free-standing, they can all use the same calling convention. The issue is only the `this` parameter, which is not part of the calling convention.

Comment: I was giving an explanation of why even if you used reinterpret_cast to change the member-function-pointer to a free-function-pointer (with the 'this' object specified as part of the parameter list) calling that function pointer may well not work. In that respect 'this' is very much part of the calling convention.

Answer (score 3):

The Win32 API is designed for the C programming language.  As such, callbacks are implemented as pointers to free-standing functions only.

In C++, a **non-static** class method has a hidden `this` parameter.  That is why your `DirectX_Hook::enumWind()` class method is not compatible with `EnumWindows()` - its signature does not match what `EnumWindows()` is expecting for a callback function.

A **static** class method, on the other hand, does not have a hidden `this` parameter.  So, it is possible to use a static class method for a Win32 callback function.

Whether you use a free-standing function, or a static class method, the `lParam` parameter can be used to pass a pointer to your `DirectX_Hook` object, or at least its internal `window` member, into the callback.

For example, using a static class method:

```cpp
class DirectX_Hook
{
public:
    static BOOL CALLBACK enumWind(HWND handle, LPARAM lp);
    HWND GetProcessWindow();
    // Other functions that doesn't matter to you.
}
extern DirectX_Hook DX_Hook;
```

```cpp
DirectX_Hook DX_Hook;

BOOL CALLBACK DirectX_Hook::enumWind(HWND handle, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD ProcID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &ProcID);
    if (GetCurrentProcessId() != ProcID)
        return TRUE;

    reinterpret_cast<DirectX_Hook*>(lp)->window = handle;
    return FALSE;
}

HWND DirectX_Hook::GetProcessWindow()
{
    window = NULL;

    EnumWindows(enumWind, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));

    RECT size;
    GetWindowRect(window, &size);
    windowSize.x = size.right - size.left;
    windowSize.y = size.bottom - size.top;

    return window;
}
```

Alternatively, using a free-standing function:

```cpp
class DirectX_Hook
{
public:
    HWND GetProcessWindow();
    // Other functions that doesn't matter to you.
}
extern DirectX_Hook DX_Hook;
```

```cpp
DirectX_Hook DX_Hook;

static BOOL CALLBACK enumWind(HWND handle, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD ProcID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &ProcID);
    if (GetCurrentProcessId() != ProcID)
        return TRUE;

    *reinterpret_cast<HWND*> = handle;
    return FALSE;
}

HWND DirectX_Hook::GetProcessWindow()
{
    window = NULL;

    EnumWindows(enumWind, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&window));

    RECT size;
    GetWindowRect(window, &size);
    windowSize.x = size.right - size.left;;
    windowSize.y = size.bottom - size.top;

    return window;
}
```